# Câmera embutida na Activity/Fragment como Instagram

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Tenho um app onde às vezes o usuário precisa tirar uma foto de um recibo durante um processo de confirmação e gostaria ter a câmera **embutida** na mesma tela neste momento (ao invés de chamar o Intent para a aplicação da câmera), independentemente do aspect ratio da câmera e/ou da foto (não precisaria necessariamente de um preview e foto quadrados como o Instagram).

Qual seria uma boa maneira de implementar isto? Algum exemplo de implementação ajudaria muito também. Agradeço a atenção desde já.

Comment: Renan, sua pergunta está muito ampla, a ideia é que você comece a fazer e tire eventuais dúvidas. Minha recomendação é que use uma biblioteca de terceiro, implementar a funcionalidade de câmera não é trivial, mas você pode fazer seguindo esse tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html. Em termos de biblioteca de terceiros, tem uma variedade para escolher: http://android-arsenal.com/tag/141.

Comment: O nome disso é SurfaceView segue o link de uma implementação http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/

Comment: Obrigado pelas orientações, vou estudar melhor o tutorial e ver as bibliotecas de terceiros e elaborar perguntas mais específicas da próxima vez.